# ng: Permission denied pipeline cicd gitlab

Tags: angular, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have a .yml file that contains my pipeline cicd of gitlab
but when execute the build job , show me this message
is a angular application
ng: Permission denied

[image]

```
image: node:latest
before_script:
  - npm install
```

this is my job

```
build-npm-prod:
  stage: build
  script:
    - rm ./package-lock.json
    - npm run build --prod
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - dist/mi-web-texo/
  only:
    - master
```

Yesterday this worked

Answer (score 0):

Check first if; as [in this instance](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56672891/6309), it is because your repository has, between yesterday and today, versioned the `node_modules` folder.

Removing that folder from the repository, adding and pushing, should allow your GitLab pipeline to run, and `ng` to operate without permission issue.

See also if [disabling cache for the job](http://www.obsis.unb.br/gitlab/help/ci/caching/index.md#disabling-cache-on-specific-jobs) would help (see [documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/caching/index.html#disable-cache-for-specific-jobs)):

```yaml
build-npm-prod:
  stage: build
  cache: []                   <=====
  script:
    - rm ./package-lock.json
    - npm run build --prod
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - dist/mi-web-texo/
  only:
    - master
```

Comment: Hi, removing node_modules folder? I don't have that folder in my gitlab repository

Comment: @SirRiT003 Do you have any other folder which should have been ignored, as per https://www.toptal.com/developers/gitignore/api/angular ?

Comment: Hello, it is a new project, I have nothing developed

Comment: I update the question adding .gitignore file ?

Comment: @SirRiT003 I was thinking about "Yesterday this worked": try and [clear the cache](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65529376/6309), to try and reproduce the build in the same conditions as yesterday.

Comment: Hi, I cleared the cache and the pipeline worked, but then I ran another pipeline and the same thing happened. I have to manually clear the cache after each pipeline otherwise I'll get the same error :/

Comment: I should add script in the .yml file?

Comment: I mean, is it possible to clear the cache for each pipeline?

Comment: @SirRiT003 It should be possible to disable the cache. See my edited answer.

Comment: Hi, I add the job, but in gitlab it shows me "job config should implement script: or trigger: keyword" error.

Comment: @SirRiT003 I meant to add to your existing job (which should have a `script` section already) an additional line `cache: {}`, in order for said job to not use caching.

Comment: Hi, at begin I had ```cache:
  paths:
    - node_modules/``` change it to  ```cache: {} ``` Is it correct ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247850/discussion-between-vonc-and-sirrit003).